# How to pass an Array as element's Attribute?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

I'm developing for sending an Array as element's attribute.

File form-list.html

```js
<dom-module id="form-list">
  <template>
    <div>{{title}} - {{owner}} </div>
    <form>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{inputAndLabel}}">
          <div><label>{{item.tag}} {{owner}}</label><input type="{{item.type}}" value="{{item.defaultValue}}"></div>
      </template>
    </form>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'form-list',
      properties: {
        owner: {
          value:"Mechanical",
        },
        inputAndLabel: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() { return []; }
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.title = 'Formulario: Usuario';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

So, for using the element and pass the inputAndLabel propertie (it's an Array) that is not work, but the owner property works (it's a string).

```
<form-list inputAndLabel="[
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Nombre' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Apellido' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Email' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Dirección' }]" owner="Eternal">
</form-list>
```

How to send an array as custom element's property?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-object-and-array-properties) you can pass an array as an element attribute it you respect the strict JSON notation.

> For object and array properties you can pass an object or array in JSON format:
>
> `<my-element book='{ "title": "Persuasion", "author": "Austen" }'></my-element>`
>
> Note that JSON requires double quotes, as shown above.

```
<form-list input-and-label='[
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Nombre" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Apellido" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Email" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Dirección" }]'   owner="Eternal">
</form-list>
```

Also note that the [corresponding attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#property-name-mapping) for the `inputAndLabel` property is written `input-and-label`.

Comment: Supersharp,

For some reason, 
I first assign  
'[  {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Nombre" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Apellido" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Email" },
        {"defaultValue": "", "type":"text", "tag": "Dirección" }]' 
to variable str,
then use
<form-list input-and-label=str></form-list>,
it do not work.

Is it necessary to put the '[{...},...,{...}]' inline?

Comment: @hjyanghj yes. you can't set a variable in the html code. As a workaround you could assign it in Javascript using setAttribute()